# How do I rebuild Configuration.php in Joomla?

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5

In a Joomla 1.5 installation, the configuration.php file was replaced by a somekind of hacker.

At the moment the website shows

> No configuration file found and no installation code available. Exiting...

How do I rebuild it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The site wasn't in my responsibility, so there is no backup.

I just downloaded the installation of Joomla 1.5 and copied the configuration.php file. It was easy enough to set the database parameters. My question is how do i rebuid it, if somehow possible. I soon as I saw the file is included in a clear installation, my problem was gone. 
Thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have a backup - and you really should have - extract the configuration.php file from the backup and re-upload.

As you are asking - I assume you do not have a backup. In that case you will need to know the following details:

database details: db_host, db_name, db_user and db_password - you can get these from your control panel (cpanel, plesk or similar).

The name of your site, and default metas (description and keywords).

Take the configuration.php-dist that ships with Joomla - redownload Joomla if you need to.

Edit the file inserting the aforementioned details. Upload to your server, renaming to configuration.php

Test - you will almost certainly make a typo or other silly mistake (I always do).

Job done - good luck with your site.

Now, before you finish, put a backup routine in place. I suggest Akeeba Backup, but a custom shell script can also zip up files and backup a database. Create your backup - and test it by re-installing the site elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

Well if you have no backup - there's no change to rebuild it, unless you can contact your hosting provider for that.
You did the right thing by extracting configuration.php file from Joomla install and configuring it manually - i would do the same.:)